# Reading text between multiple newline characters and whitespaces using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-re, findall, textmatching

I'm trying to read these underlined headings using regex.

These headings have more than two newline characters and more than two whitespace characters before the start of the heading. It has ONE whitespace and two newline characters after the heading. The heading is in all CAPITAL letters.

I tried with `r"(\n{2,}\s{2,})(?:([A-Z]+)\s([A-Z]*))"` but it did not work.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you tried and describe where you got stuck. The tags suggest you have already tried something really specific - that would be a good starting point.

Comment: Also please paste the text here so that we don't have to retype everything.

Comment: @Grismar added the regex I tried.

Comment: @SmirithikaChandrasegar You did good job. Your regex can get `ROBOT ` and `TRAFFIC LIGHT ` from first group if you move `?:` to first group like `(?:\n{2,}\s{2,})(([A-Z]+)\s([A-Z]*))`. You will know you are not wrong with this link https://regex101.com/r/CM0geB/1

Comment: I'll try with this. Thank you. @doctorgu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work.

```
print(re.findall(r'\n{2,}\s{2,}([A-Z\s]+)\s\n', data, re.X))
```

based on the snippet above, returns:

```
['ROBOT ', 'TRAFFIC LIGHT ', 'TRAFFIC LIGHT ']
```